# ASP.NET MVC controllers with identical names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have an ASP.NET MVC web application, where I'd like to have a separate "admin" area (accessible via `http://example.com/admin`) and a regular area, available for all users.

In both these parts of the site I have a `/blogs` section, but when accessing `http://example.com/admin/blogs` I want to be presented with admin interface for blogs, whereas usual `http://example.com/blogs` should just list all blogs.

And the problem itself is: how do I get ASP.NET MVC to instantiate appropriate controllers, provided that there are two `BlogsController`s: one in `Site.Admin` namespace, and the other is in `Site.Sitefront` namespace?

Granted, I could rename admin controller to `BlogsAdminController`, but I'd like to keep the names as they already are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil Haack has a nice blogpost about this: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx